# Can ${\bf bb}^T = \bf I$ hold for any field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\bf b$ be a column vector and $\bf I$ the identity matrix. Is there in some way for some field of elements that

$${\bf bb}^T = {\bf I}$$

can hold?

Comment: compare ranks of LHS and RHS

Comment: Yes it seems unreasonable unless $\bf I$ is 1x1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of anything, $bb^T$ has rank $\le1$, because $(bb^T)x=\alpha b$ for the scalar $\alpha=b^Tx$.