# Can ${\bf bb}^T = \bf I$ hold for anything which is not a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was thinking something like this.

Some kind of number equipped with multiplication which behaves like returning 1 if the largest prime factor (with exponent $\geq 1$) has exponent divisible by two

For example 
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}2\\3\\5\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}2&3&5\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}4&6&10\\6&9&15\\10&15&25\end{array}\right]$$

And then calculating largest prime exponents:

$$ans = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}2&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2\end{array}\right]$$

And divisibility by 2:

$$ans = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$

I doubt it would be a group. How would it behave algebraically?

Comment: So you are not actually redefining the *multiplication* of scalars, but rather the *sum* of scalars: multiplication appears to be just the same.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I don't see any addition carried out. The outer product will have one scalar multiplication per element and no additions. No?

Comment: Ah, true. Notational issue: I was thinking, as it kind of looks like, that you were defining a product of matrices. Perhaps, you may want to define it directly as a function that takes in two vectors and returns a matrix, rather than indulging in a notation that is strongly reminescent of the product between two matrices (for which the last operation applied to the entries is actually a sum, not a product).

Comment: Yes for anything larger than vectors we would need to define + between elements also for the matrix product to make sense.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717136/can-bf-bbt-bf-i-hold-for-any-field).

Comment: @DietrichBurde it's not the same question. That one was for elements of fields and then rank makes sense.

Comment: @mathreadler I know. However I feel this question serves as a background for others who want to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "anything" is assocative it's impossible.

Consider two first elements of $b$ then we have $b_1^2=1, b_2b_1=0, \ldots\Rightarrow 0=b_2b_1\cdot b_1=b_2b_1^2=b_2\cdot1=b_2\Rightarrow bb^\top\ne I.$

If "anything" is non associative (multiplication of matricies can be well defined although it will be nonassociative) it's possible.

Let $0, 1, a, b, a+b, 1+a, 1+b, 1+a+b$ be all elements of linear non-associative algebra under 2-element field with mutiplication table of basic elements: $1a=a1=a, 1b=b1=b, ab=ba=0.$

For this "anything" we have $(a,b)^\top (a,b)=I$

PS. But I see no point in introducing multiplication of matrices for such "anything"